# How do I vertically resize results in a find window?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

This is what my find window looks like in outlook:

[image]

Notice all the white space between the controls and results.

When I resize the window vertically, the results don't move up.  I have to keep this window the same size to see the result.

The box I have highlighted in red is the part where I move my mouse slowly up and down searching for some sort of ability to move the results up.

Yet I cannot.

Is there another way to bring the "results" portion of this screen up?

Comment: Are you using Outlook 2013? What is the OS?

Comment: Have you tried maximizing the window?